# UDF over the array elements in Pyspark also add the static element

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i have a dataframe like below,

```
df.select("col1").show(1,False)
col1
-------------
[[2,1,0,1,,free],[3,1,0,1,4,free]]
```

another way to show :)

```
df.select(to_json(struct("col1")))show(1,False)

col1
-----------------
{"col1":[{ "0":"2","1":"1","2":"0","3":"1","5":"free"},{"0":"3","1":"1","2":"0","3":"1","4":"4","5":"free"}]}
```

now I want to achieve the below data frame, there is a structure to be created from the existing column and also needs to add the new static field 'value:zzz'

```
col1
--------------
{"col1":[{"1":"1","2":"0","3":"1","5":"free","value":"ZZZ","newattrib":{"0":"2"}},{"1":"1","2":"0","3":"1","4":"4","5":"free","value":"ZZZ","newattrib":{"0":"3"}}]}
```

Please suggest to me the way to achieve this.

Comment: just looking at input/output, we're supposed to understand what you are doing ? please explain it logically ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `transform` function

```
df = (df
      .selectExpr("""transform(col1, v -> struct(v.`1` `1`,
                                                 v.`2` `2`,
                                                 v.`3` `3`,
                                                 v.`4` `4`,
                                                 v.`5` `5`,
                                                 'ZZZ' value,
                                                 struct(v.`0` `0`) newattrib)) col1""")
      .select(to_json(struct("col1")).alias('col1'))
      )
df.show(truncate=False)

# +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |col1                                                                                                                                              |
# +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |{"col1":[{"1":1,"2":0,"3":1,"5":"free","value":"ZZZ","newattrib":{"0":2}},{"1":1,"2":0,"3":1,"4":4,"5":"free","value":"ZZZ","newattrib":{"0":3}}]}|
# +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```