# add the static value in the each array contents in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe like below

df.show(2,False)

```
 col1
 ----------
 [[1,2][3,4]]
```

I want to add the some static value in each array content like this

```
  col2
  ----------
  [[1,2,"Value"],[3,4,"value]]
```

Please suggest me the way to achieve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UDF over the array elements in Pyspark also add the static element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68800620/udf-over-the-array-elements-in-pyspark-also-add-the-static-element)

Comment: Please, do not post multiple time the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**explode** the array and then use **`concat`** function to add the value to the array, finally use **collect_list** to recreate nested array.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("spark_parti_id",spark_partition_id()).\
withColumn("col2",explode(col("col1"))).\
withColumn("col2",concat(col("col2"),array(lit(2)))).\
groupBy("spark_parti_id").\
agg(collect_list(col("col2")).alias("col2")).\
drop("spark_parti_id").\
show(10,False)

#+----------------------+
#|col2                  |
#+----------------------+
#|[[1, 2, 2], [3, 4, 2]]|
#+----------------------+
```